# Flutter Failed to handle method call E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 8279):

Tags: android, flutter, dart, error-handling

Getting the following error on startup in a loop continuously and also I found that one of my SQLite databases is also not working properly, can't understand because of what error is being caused. Please help to solve the error below...

I have also attached pubspec.yaml and flutter --version output

```
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 8279): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 8279): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported, use openfile
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 8279):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:165)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 8279):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:146)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 8279):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:698)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 8279):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1412)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 8279):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1356)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 8279):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin.getClipboardData(PlatformPlugin.java:295)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 8279):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin.access$700(PlatformPlugin.java:26)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 8279):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin$1.getClipboardData(PlatformPlugin.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 8279):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformChannel.java:141)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 8279):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 8279):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 8279):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 8279):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 8279):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 8279):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 8279):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 8279):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 8279):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 8279):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

flutter --version output

```
Framework • revision 1aafb3a8b9 (3 weeks ago) • 2020-11-13 09:59:28 -0800
Engine • revision 2c956a31c0
Tools • Dart 2.10.4
```

pubspec.yaml

```
description: Video conferencing app developed by Jagadish Prasad Pattanaik 2020.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 2.0.1+4004

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  jitsi_meet: ^2.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.4
  firebase_core: ^0.5.3
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.5
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.10.0
  share: ^0.6.5+4
  url_launcher: ^5.7.10
  rate_my_app: ^0.7.2
  shared_preferences: 0.5.12+4
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.6.3
  provider: ^4.3.2+2
  random_string: ^2.1.0
  sqflite: ^1.3.2+1
  path_provider: ^1.6.22
  path: ^1.7.0
  fluttertoast: ^7.1.5
  package_info: ^0.4.3
  date_time_picker: ^1.1.0
  carousel_slider: ^2.3.1
  image_gallery_saver: ^1.6.6
  quick_actions: ^0.4.0+10
  cached_network_image: ^2.4.1
  device_info: ^1.0.0
  dots_indicator: ^1.2.0
  argon_buttons_flutter: ^1.0.6
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.2+1
  connectivity: ^2.0.2
  badges: ^1.1.4
  overlay_support: ^1.0.5
  webview_flutter: ^1.0.7
  flutter_offline: ^0.3.0
  in_app_review: ^1.0.3
  in_app_update: ^1.1.14
  pull_to_refresh: ^1.6.3
  timeago: ^2.0.29

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/schedule.png
    - assets//images/clock.png
    - assets//images/chat.jpg
    - assets/images/startjoin.jpg
    - assets/images/stay.jpg
    - assets/images/unlimited.jpg
    - assets/images/secured.jpg
    - assets/images/multiple.jpg
    - assets/images/lowmode.jpg
    - assets/images/youtube.jpg
    - assets/images/waiting.jpg
    - assets/images/password.jpg
    - assets/images/search.png

  uses-material-design: true

  fonts:
    - family: OpenSans
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: include your `flutter --vsersion` output and your project pubspec file code

Comment: Can't find anything about this error. Can you isolate what line in your code causes this ? Looks like it has something to do with opening files.

Comment: I also can not get which line error is being caused but when I close the app and start again it doesn't give any error but on the first time it gives on a loop but the app keeps working.

Comment: By any chance were you using a TextFormField in your project? I'm experiencing the same problem. Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: No, I was using TextField and yes I managed to solve it...I am answering this question please follow it and if it helps then please upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by checking my mysqlite database codes, I found an error that was 2 parameters had the same naming which was causing the error. If u face this type of error then please check your mysqlite codes thoroughly.